# how to add data from arraylist to shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have async task where i am getting data from server in JSONArray format. I want to save that data in shared preferences and display it in list view. i am using adapter. 
I have tried but not getting anything

```
   JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(strServerResponse);
   JSONObject jsonObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
       pojo = new Pojo();
       JSONObject jobj2 = arr.getJSONObject(i);
       String tipoftheday = jobj2.optString("tipsoftheday");
       ArrayList<String> tii = new ArrayList<String>();
       tii.add(tipoftheday);
   }
```

this tip of the day contains multiple data which i want to save in shared preferences and then show in list view. pojo is a class where i have defined setters and getters.

```
  ArrayList<Pojo> tips;
  tips = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
  pojo.setTip(mydatafromsharedprefernces);
  tips.add(pojo);
  tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(TipsActivity.this, tips);
  listTips.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
```

how to add the data in shared prefernces. can anyone please help me.

Comment: Better you convert JSON data to String and store in one shared Preferences.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985925/how-to-store-arraylist-in-shared-preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you know how to declare object of sharedPreference and how to use Editor object.

convert your arraylist to List<>

```
List<String> listTemp=tii ;
```

Add whole list in sharedPreference :

```
editor.putStringSet("key", listTemp);
editor.commit();
```

Retrieve list :

```
Set<String> set = editor.getStringSet("key", null);
```

Comment: getting error  Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>', required: 'java.util.Set<java.lang.String>

Comment: List<String> listTemp=tii ;
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(listTemp);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences( "MyPref",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putStringSet("tipoftheday", temp);
editor.commit();
now how can i set the value in pojo class

Comment: i have used pojo.setTip(set.toString()); but i am getting only onevalue

Answer (score 3):

We have method "`putStringSet`" in "`SharedPreferences.Editor`".

```
putStringSet(String key, Set<String> values)
```

You have to convert `ArrayList<Pojo>` to Set.
But Pojo must be serializable.

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

and use the above method.

Check the following link.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Answer (score 0):

you mentioned you get data in json.Store that json string in shared preference. decode it when you get back from shared preferences.