# how to store ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data into sharedpreferences?

Tags: android

I have one "ArrayList> List_Data =new ArrayList>();"

but my requirement is to store that List_Data into sharedpreference . Please Help me out.

Comment: Use gson library it is really easy to store list using it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store arraylist values in shared preference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985925/how-to-store-arraylist-values-in-shared-preference)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert your array or object to JSON and store into shared pref

for storing:

```
SharedPreferences db=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Editor collection = db.edit();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String arrayList1 = gson.toJson(arrayList);

collection.putString(key, arrayList1);
collection.commit();
```

for retrieving

```
SharedPreferences db=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String arrayListString = db.getString(key, null);  
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayObject>>() {}.getType();
ArrayList<ArrayObject> arrayList = gson.fromJson(arrayListString, type);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use shared preference only if you have a relatively small collection of key-values that you'd like to save

Here's how to save List> into shared preference

serialize it using using gson or any other library of your choice

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String serializedMapData = gson.toJson(mapList);
preferenceObj.edit().putString("key", mapList)
```

again convert it back into object using gson

```
String mapListString= preferenceObj.getString("key");
List<Map<String, String>> map = gson.fromJson(string, List.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Serialize your object to json String with Gson or any other, then store this String in SP. To get this object: get the String and deserialize it to your array.