# NullPointerException on initialised ArrayList object

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for my problem and tried to rectify it. But the error of `NullPointerException` is not going.
The variable `dataa` is what I'm getting from previous activity and variable `dataa_OLD` is what I'm retrieving from the `TinyDB`. I've referred [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523898/how-to-store-arraylisthashmapstring-string-data-into-sharedpreferences) for storing `HashMap` data-list into Sharedpreferences.

```
...
 List<Map<String, String>> dataa= new ArrayList<>();
List<Map<String, String>> dataa_OLD= new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> mapp = new HashMap<String, String>();
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

//Retrieving HashMap-lists from TinyDB
Gson gson = new Gson();
String mapListString= tinyDB.getString("DATA");
String mapListStringOLD= tinyDB.getString("DATA_OLD");
Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Map<String,String>>>() {}.getType();
dataa = gson.fromJson(mapListString,type);
dataa_OLD = gson.fromJson(mapListStringOLD,type);

if(dataa.size()!=0) {
        for (Map<String, String> map : dataa) {
            parked_addrs.add(map.get("ADDRS"));//adding address part in another list
        }
        tinyDB.putListString("paddrslist", parked_addrs);

        if(dataa_OLD!=null) {
            for (Map<String, String> map : dataa) {    //adding new-list in old-list one by one
                mapp.put("ADDRS", map.get("ADDRS"));
                mapp.put("DATE", map.get("DATE"));
                dataa_OLD.add(mapp);
            }
        }
        else {
            mapp.put("ADDRS","");
            mapp.put("DATE","");
            dataa_OLD.add(0,mapp);
            dataa_OLD.addAll(dataa); // Line on which getting the error
        }
    }
```

The `stack-trace`

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: com.example.acer.mylocationmap, PID: 30082
>                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.acer.mylocationmap/com.example.acer.mylocationmap.DisplayStorageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.add(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
>                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void java.util.List.add(int, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
>                                                                                       at com.example.acer.mylocationmap.DisplayStorageActivity.onCreate(DisplayStorageActivity.java:115)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Is there anything that I'm missing? Please help me out.

Comment: Can you please provide the `stack-trace` of your `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Which line is the exception being thrown on? It would help if you posted the full error text in your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Izruo added the stack-trace

Comment: @Keara Yeah added as comment in the edit.

Comment: if(dataa_OLD!=null) {  else condition is using dataa_OLD then you have a null pointer

Comment: @diegoveloper Yeah I added it later on as before that I was getting the same error on all the places wherever I was using `dataa_OLD` in the code... So thought this would help anyway but it didn't :(

Answer (score 0):

parked_addrs seems to be null at that point.

Comment: But the exception is thrown on `dataa_OLD` variable line.. does it mean something else? Because I'm having this statement above all for parked_addrs `ArrayList<String> parked_addrs = new ArrayList<>();
parked_addrs=tinyDB.getListString("paddrslist");`