# How a service can post message to a not yet running main activity?

Tags: android, android-service

I have a **background service** that receive notification data messages and i want that is the main activity of the app who will process then. When the main activity is running, i can send the data message to it via `LocalBroadcastManager`, but my problem is **when the main activity is not running** ! How the service can send message to the main activity in the way that the main activity will receive the message **when it's will start** ?

Comment: you can save that data in local storage either database or shared preference and when your activity starts check for the value and proceed accordingly

Comment: how you will do this using shared preference ? i mean is their anyway using shared preference to store data in `row` (several records with their fields) like in database ?

Comment: You can save array list in shared preference too

Comment: that sound perfect ! deserve to be the answer :)

Comment: Posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

you can save that data in local storage either database or shared preference and when your activity starts check for the value and proceed accordingly.

Also you can save custom array list too in shared preference using gson library easily

Comment: do you have example of using array list ? i can't find one

Comment: What kind of data you want to store

Comment: string data, in array, like a database with field

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985925/save-arraylist-in-shared-preference